# mariadb galera cluster db control

Tags: mariadb, galera

Currently,I am having mariadb galera cluster operating on two instances of maria db and each node working as Master, replicating data seamlessly. Now, on one node, I want to control one of my database, table etc to not replicate. Can we control the replication behavior to the layer of table, database etc.

Answer (score 0):

By having only 2 nodes on a Galera cluster, you eliminate automatic recovery from a node fault.

By having a db that exists on only one node, you are eliminating the ability to failover by any means.

So, I ask, why use Galera at all?

Back to your question...  Galera does not want you to do what you are asking.  *Maybe* there is some letting to let you have MyISAM or MEMORY without replicating it.  I don't think you can avoid replicating InnoDB tables.